# Entity Framework Code First: Custom Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship

```
public class User
{
   public int Id {get;set;}

   public string Name {get;set}

   public ICollection<User> Followers {get;set;}
   public ICollection<User> Following {get;set;}
}
```

My Model looks like above, Entity framework automatically creates A table and `UserUser`  with rows `User_ID` and `User_ID1` in DB to map this model. I want to map that table and rows myself.

How can i do that, Thanx!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx) about [Many-valued Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx):

> Many-to-Many Associations
>   The association between Category and Item is a many-to-many
>   association, as can be seen in the above class diagram. a many-to-many
>   association mapping hides the intermediate association table from the
>   application, so you don’t end up with an unwanted entity in your
>   domain model. That said, In a real system, you may not have a
>   many-to-many association since my experience is that there is almost
>   always other information that must be attached to each link between
>   associated instances (such as the date and time when an item was added
>   to a category) and that the best way to represent this information is
>   via an intermediate association class (In EF, you can map the
>   association class as an entity and map two one-to-many associations
>   for either side.).
>
> In a many-to-many relationship, the join table (or link table, as some
>   developers call it) has two columns: the foreign keys of the Category
>   and Item tables. The primary key is a composite of both columns. **In EF
>   Code First, many-to-many associations mappings can be customized with
>   a fluent API code like this:**

```
    class ItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item> {
    internal ItemConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasMany(i => i.Categories)
            .WithMany(c => c.Items)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("ItemId");
                mc.MapRightKey("CategoryId");
                mc.ToTable("ItemCategory");
            });
    } }
```

Register this configuration in your DbContext's  (you using the DbContext api right?) like this:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ItemConfiguration());
  }
```

Good luck, hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

To map an entity to itself, you would do something like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Followers)
        .WithMany().ForeignKey(u => u.FollowerId);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

its hard to tell without seeing your database model though, and how you actually relate the followers to the user.